# Weighted effect coding in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, anova

I have a data set with a categorical variable and a continuous dependent variable, and I want to know the effect of deviation of mean of each category from the overall mean.

```
str(dat)
'data.frame':   380 obs. of  2 variables:
$ Pgene_3X     : num  0 0 0.08 0 0.048 ...
$ CT           : Factor w/ 22 levels "1:ATG1","10:ATC3",..: 15 15 21 21 21 21 21 21 21 15 ...
```

As the groups in the categorical variable are not balanced I want to use weighted effect coding in R.

I tried the package "wec".

```
dat$CTatg1 <- contr.wec("dat$CT",ref="1:ATG1")
```

But it gives me an error:

> Error in contr.treatment(n.cat, base = ref) : not enough degrees of freedom to define contrasts

This function works on the dummy BMI data provided with R but not on my data. 
Is there any other way to approach this problem. How can I compare the mean of each "CT" level with the overall weighted mean?

Comment: I think you want `dat$CTatg1 <- contr.wec(dat$CT,ref="1:ATG1")`, i.e. do not pub the `dat$CT` in quotes

Comment: Oh, sorry that was a very stupid mistake and I spent a lot of time around it. Thanks a lot for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the manual of ["wec" package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wec/wec.pdf).
I suspect that you may need to replace your argument "ref" with "omitted".